# Thumbnail hover scaling within thumbnail size

Tags: css, hover

I am trying to get a scale effect when I hover over a thumb, as in this Codepen example (first thumb, the Lily effect):

http://codepen.io/intermedion/pen/BQVJEx

I modified the above example to remove the figure/figcaption, and I used a flexbox layout for the thumb grid, see this pen:

http://codepen.io/intermedion/pen/dOKrWQ?editors=1100

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <a href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-1.jpg">

          <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-1.jpg">

      </a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-3.jpg">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-3.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  

/* CSS */ 
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.row div {
  flex: auto;
  width: 160px;
  margin: 6px 12px;
}

.row div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/*** EFFECTS ***/
.row img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;  
}

.row img {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;

}

.row:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
  transform: scale(1.15);
}
```

I tried various options, including setting sizes on the thumbs, adding figure/figcaption - the thumbs scale, but over and beyond the thumbnail size, which is not what I want.

I am starting to suspect that it may be the flexbox layout that is causing the scaling beyond the rendered thumb size, but I am not sure.

Is there any way to do the scaling within the rendered thumb with a flexbox layout?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot `overflow:hidden` for the `div`:

```
.row div {
  flex: auto;
  width: 160px;
  margin: 6px 12px;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a:link { text-decoration: none; } 
a:visited { text-decoration: none; } 
a:hover { text-decoration: none;}


html {
  background: #2b303b;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

/*** LAYOUT ***/

.wrap {
  max-width: 660px;
  margin: 1.5em auto 1em auto;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: #2e333f;
  background-color: rgba(32, 38, 52, 0.6);
  background: #242B3A;
  font-family: "PT Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: rgba(127, 133, 147, 0.8);
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}

/*** GRID ***/

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.row div {
  flex: auto;
  width: 160px;
  margin: 6px 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/*** EFFECTS ***/
.row img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;  
}

.row img {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  
}

.row div:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
  transform: scale(1.15);
}

/*** CAPTIONS ***/

/*
.grid figure {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px 1%;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 480px;
  max-height: 360px;
  width: 48%;
  background: #3085a3;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
*/
/*
.grid figure img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <a href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-1.jpg">
        
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-1.jpg">
       
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <a href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-3.jpg">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-3.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed, it works now exactly as I want it , thank you!

Comment: Oh, also the hover in:  `.row:hover img{...}` should be `.row img:hover{...}`, otherwise all the images in the row will scale at the same time when hovering over one image.